# Is there a way to use a parameter to set a variable name?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't really know how to explain this, but is there a way to place the name of a variable using a string? i have some code to explain my question:

I have my User Class with a username, id, and a lot of other stuff.

```
public User User;
```

and I have function that download a json with all that information

```
public IEnumerator getDataArray(string function, string value, targetObject)
{
    queuedDownloads++;

    Dictionary<string, string> headerDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    headerDict.Add(function, value);
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        headerDict.Add("UserID", userID.ToString());
#endif
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(downloadUrl, headerDict);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log("<color=red>" + www.error + "</color>");
        string errorMessage = www.error;
        Debug.Log("There was an error getting the data list: " + errorMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        string result = HTMLEntityUtility.Decode(www.downloadHandler.text);
        if (result.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("EMPTY");
        }
        else
        {
            //here i want that targetObject becomes the name of the given value
            //the wanted line here is:
            //User = JsonExtension.GetArrayFromJson<User>(result);
            targetObject = JsonExtension.GetArrayFromJson<targetObject>(result);
            queuedDownloads--;
        }
    }

    yield return null;
}
```

I want to use this function to get the information with a webrequest and save that data in the user class.
to start this i want to use something like this:

```
    //here I want to give which data it has to request, what value has to be used and in which variable this has to be stored
    StartCoroutine(getDataArray("getUserData", "1", User));
```

I have multiple classes that i want to fill like this but I don't want 14 different functions that are the same except 1 variable.
Is there a way to make the targetObject from above function as the name of the variable I give in the coroutine?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Now I get the feeling your solution lies somewhere in generics, however first it needs to be clear what you actually require. What are you trying to accomplish by using the `IEnumerator` you return here. Because you're not really enumerating anything, the first item that is enumerated is the return of `www.SendWebRequest()`, the second item that is enumerated is always `null` and then the enumeration is done. Are you trying to return both the raw result from the webrequest and a class instance containing the json data?

Comment: @Knoop in Unity a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) is always implemented as an `IEnumerator` without return value. calling `yield return null;` basically just means wait one frame while `yield return www.SendWebRequest();` means wait until the request is either finished or failed. Using `yield return null;` in the end of a routine is however completely senseless ;)

Comment: @derHugo Ah I see, admittedly not that familiar with Unity so that's one me. Thanks for explaining:-)

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on how that `JsonExtension.GetArrayFromJson` works of course but I think you could make your routine [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/):

```
// The type parameter T is hereby extracted automatically from the reference
// you pass into "targetObject"
public IEnumerator getDataArray<T>(string function, string value, ref T targetObject)
{
    queuedDownloads++;

    var headerDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    headerDict.Add(function, value);

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    headerDict.Add("UserID", userID.ToString());
#endif

    using(var www = UnityWebRequest.Post(downloadUrl, headerDict))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"There was an error getting the data list: <color=red>{www.error}</color>");
            return;
        }

        var result = HTMLEntityUtility.Decode(www.downloadHandler.text);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
        {
            Debug.LogError("The result is EMPTY!");
            return;
        }

        // Here you use the generic type parameter "T"
        targetObject = JsonExtension.GetArrayFromJson<T>(result);
    }

    queuedDownloads--;
}
```

You would call it like e.g.

```
User user;
SomeOtherClass someOtherClass;

StartCoroutine(getDataArray("getUserData", "1", user));
StartCoroutine(getDataArray("getSomeOtherData", "XY", someOtherClass));
```

as said passing in the type parameter `T` e.g. like

```
StartCoroutine(getDataArray<User>("getUserData", "1", user));
```

is not necessary / would be redundant as it is automatically extracted from the type of the object you pass into `targetObject`.

---

In general:

Note that right now you will be able to start your Coroutines with the correct references etc **BUT** ... you will never know **if** or **when** an actual result will be received.

You should probably rather implement a callback which handles the data once it is actually there e.g. like

```
public IEnumerator getDataArray<T>(string function, string value, Action<T> onSuccess)
{
    [.....]

    // Here you use the generic type parameter "T"
    T targetObject = JsonExtension.GetArrayFromJson<T>(result);

    queuedDownloads--;
    
    // Invoke the callback
    onSuccess?.Invoke(targetObject);
}
```

And call it like e.g.

```
StartCoroutine(getDataArray("getUserData", "1", HandleReceivedUser));

...

private void HandleReceivedUser(User user)
{
    // do something with the user
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `targetObject` have an `out` or `ref` modifier in the first part of this answer? Otherwise it'll just override a local reference and won't be visible outside `getDataArray`

Comment: @Knoop yep forgot that, thanks! `out` wouldn't work since the routine doesn't wait until setting it so if you are going to use it right after the `StartCoroutine` call it would always be `null`